# How to Write Confirm dialogue Box Code in Controller? For Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here Is My Sample Code- Its About Calculation Like Bank WithDraw Method.. If User Withdraw is Negative value then Show a Dialogue Box (yes/No) option ...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult withdraw()
{
   if(Sum<0)
       {
          Code For Dialogue Box;
              if(Yes)
                 //Do
               else
                 //Exists
       }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: You are mixing concerns. Displaying a dialog box is done by the view, the controller has nothing to do with that

Comment: handle it with javascript

Comment: Thank You For Clear My concept .. And Ur time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Euphoria's** answer is one way to achieve your goal. But why should I call to server when I can check the withdraw value and show an alert message in my client side itself.

I would suggest to call a jquery/js function on button click or whatever, like bellow,

```
$('#withdrawBtn').click(function(){
//Take the withdraw fields value. Let's say it's a text box with ID myWithdrawTextBox
if($('#myWithdrawTextBox').val() > 0)
 {
   //Post to your server. I mean call your Action Method
 }
else
  alert('Please enter correct amount');
})
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank You Very Much.. I will try :)

Comment: It's Work find .. :)

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
 public ActionResult withdraw()
    {
       if(Sum<0)
           {
              Code For Dialogue Box;
                  if(Yes)
                    ViewBag.Result="true"; 
                   else
                     ViewBag.Result="false";
           }

    return View();
    }
```

I assume you have jquery in layout or in page, view:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    if(@ViewBag.Result="true"){

    alert("true");

    }
    })


    </script>
```